# What is an action verb that is less committal than "invite" but more specific than "share"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Imagine you are looking through a selection of events. One event takes your fancy and you want to see if a friend is interested too. I am looking for a verb that captures this. You are not quite inviting them, that is too concrete. On the other hand, you are sharing but you expect a response. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you'll struggle to find a single word, but if you say something like "Oh, I like the look of the British Light Music concert next week at the Sydney Hall. Is that your sort of thing?" you are **testing the waters**.

Comment: Or "sounding him out".

Answer (score 2):

You might like:

[***float***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/float) : *v*  To offer for consideration; suggest: *floated my idea to the committee.*

Using *float* you might say

> I saw the event poster and *floated* the idea of going to a few of my friends, but I haven't gotten any response yet.

And of course there is ***suggest***

Answer (score 2):

Consider ***broach***

> to mention or suggestion for the first time
>
> *to broach a subject*

Answer (score 0):

*This event looks great! Might you want to **join** me?*

Answer (score -1):

Dispatch dawned on me immediately. Also, dispense or distribute would be meaningful and pertinent to what is being requested. Propose, request or ask, too.

Comment: Forget about dispense and distribute; I hadn't read the description of your post beforehand.

Comment: If you want to revise your answer, please do so by editing it.